# How to store an array of prefabs together with configuration parameters

Tags: unity, c#, gameobject

I have attached the following script to a number of weapon prefabs:

```
public class WeaponScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public enum Direction {Right, Straight, Left};
    public Direction weaponDir;        

    void Start () {
        prepareDirection (weaponDir);
    }

    void prepareDirection(Direction dir)    {
        if (dir == Direction.Straight)  {
            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);

        }

        else if(dir == Direction.Left)  {
            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, 0, -30);
        }

        else if(dir == Direction.Right) {
            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, 0, 30);

        }
    }
}
```

I also added the following script to an empty game object SetupWeapon:

```
public class SetupWeaponsScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject[] weaponPrefabs; 
    public GameObject[] weapons;

    void Start ()
    {   
        weapons = new GameObject[weaponPrefabs.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < weaponPrefabs.Length; i++)
        {
            weapons[i] = Instantiate(weaponPrefabs[i]) as GameObject;
        }

    }
}
```

When I select my SetupWeapon object, I am able to populate the `weaponPrefabs` array with the weapon prefabs I want to use, but I can't directly alter their parameters in that same inspector view. I want to be able to override the direction of each weapon prefab in the list, rather than use the value that's stored on the prefab itself.

How can I create the `weaponsSetupScript` in such a way that I can set the direction enum for each weapon entry at the same time that I set select the prefab in the editor? I believe it might have something to do with inheritance, just not too sure how to go about it though.

Comment: It's not immediately clear what's not working about your present example. It looks like you should be able to select your various weapon prefab objects in the Project window, set their `weaponDir` in the Inspector for the `WeaponScript` class, and then they'll be instantiated with the value you've set. Is it that you want to override this direction after instantiating the prefabs? You can do this by storing and instantiating the prefabs as the `WeaponScript` type rather than `GameObject`, or by using `GetComponent` to access their `WeaponScript` on demand. Or is there some other issue here?

Comment: @DMGregory I want to select both the weapon prefab and it's enum value at the same time for each element of `weaponPrefabs` using the editor. Something like a tuple of the weapon prefab  and the `Direction` enum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a tuple - a type that contains your two pieces of data together in a package - then just define one. ;)

```
public class SetupWeaponsScript {

    // Here's our tuple combining a weapon prefab and a direction.
    [System.Serializable]
    public struct DirectedWeapon {
        public WeaponScript weapon;
        public WeaponScript.Direction direction;
    }

    // The prefabs array is now this tuple type.
    public DirectedWeapon[] weaponPrefabs;
    public WeaponScript[] weapons;

    void Start ()
    {   
        weapons = new WeaponScript[weaponPrefabs.Length]; 

        for (int i = 0; i < weaponPrefabs.Length; i++)
        {
            // Using typed Instantiate to save a GetComponent call.
            weapons[i] = Instantiate<WeaponScript>(weaponPrefabs[i].weapon);
            weapons[i].weaponDir = weaponPrefabs[i].direction;
        }        
    }    
}
```

In the Inspector it looks like this, so you can populate the prefab and direction side-by-side:

[image: Example of populating the weaponPrefabs array in the Inspector]

Comment: this is awesome. I am trying to achieve something that I don't think warrants a new question. I attached the above code to a `WeaponGroup` empty game object. I realized that I need to be organizing the weapons into several groups to add other group functionality to the above script. So I made another game object `WeaponGroups` and made `WeaponGroup` a prefab. I am a bit confused as to how I'll get the editor properties from the above script (`SetupWeaponsScript`)  for another script (`SetupWeaponGroupsScript`). Hence having a `WeaponGroup` property that follows the above.

Comment: Generally I would like to know how I can transfer the properties above so that each `WeaponGroup` (is added to a newly created `SetupWeaponGroupsScript` which will have an array of `WeaponGroup` objects) is setup in a way similar to what is done below, so that I make the `SetupWeaponsScript` properties hidden to the inspector and visible through `SetupWeaponGroupsScript`.

Comment: That sounds to me like a new question. Maybe include a mock-up of what you want to see in the inspector, to make sure it's unambiguous what the answer should achieve as an end goal.

Comment: Here is a link to the hierarchy I would to see in the inspector http://imgur.com/a/EBO34. As I mentioned above, I have attached the above script to a WeaponGroup GameObject and made a prefab.

Comment: That looks like an array of DirectedWeapon arrays, ie. `DirectedWeapon[][]`

Comment: Yeah, that's true

Comment: How can I use  `DirectedWeapon[][]` to access all the other properties in another script, as in the image?

Comment: After given it some thought I decided to post a new question https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/142520/how-to-access-arrays-of-prefabs-and-other-properties-through-the-inspector-in-a