# How to access arrays of prefabs and other properties through the inspector in a given hierarchy

Tags: unity, c#

The script below is added to an empty game object `WeaponGroup`, which can be populated using the editor. I have made a new game object `WeaponGroups` which should have a script `SetupWeaponGroupsScript`. How can I transfer the properties below so that each `WeaponGroup` (`SetupWeaponGroupsScript` will have an array of `WeaponGroup` objects) is setup in a way similar to what is done below, so that I make the `SetupWeaponsScript` properties hidden to the inspector and populate them through `SetupWeaponGroupsScript`?

```
public class SetupWeaponsScript {

// Here's our tuple combining a weapon prefab and a direction.
[System.Serializable]
public struct DirectedWeapon {
    public WeaponScript weapon;
    public WeaponScript.Direction direction;
}

// The prefabs array is now this tuple type.
public DirectedWeapon[] weaponPrefabs;
public WeaponScript[] weapons;

void Start ()
{  
    weapons = new WeaponScript[weaponPrefabs.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < weaponPrefabs.Length; i++)
    {
        // Using typed Instantiate to save a GetComponent call.
        weapons[i] = Instantiate<WeaponScript>(weaponPrefabs[i].weapon);
        weapons[i].weaponDir = weaponPrefabs[i].direction;
    }      
}  
}
```

In other words I'd like to have the following hierarchy in the editor:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use `ScriptableObject`. Create a script called `WeaponGroups` and put this inside:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class WeaponGroup{
    public Weapon[] weapons;
}

[System.Serializable]
public enum WeaponType{
    SWORD, GUN, BOW
}

[System.Serializable]
public enum WeaponDirection{
    LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Weapon{
    public WeaponType type;
    public WeaponDirection direction;
    public int damage;
}


[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "WeaponGroups", menuName = "Custom/WeaponGroups")]
public class WeaponGroups : ScriptableObject {
    public WeaponGroup[] groups;
}
```

Now do:

[image]

and here go you:

[image]

You can use your `ScriptableObject` wherever you want. Just drop it somewhere :)

Comment: Your WeaponGroups (and possibly the Weapons themselves) could probably stand to be structs here. That'll save a pointer indirection when iterating through the array of them.

Comment: That's a point. I wrote that in case someone learns `C#` before `C` and have no idea what a `struct` is :) I'll change it. Thanks!